# How to retrieve dictionary data from request in python?

Tags: python, flask

```
@app.route('/ATGDataSubmission', methods=['POST'])
def ATGDataSubmissions(): 
           print request.data //prints none
           receivedData = request.form
           print receivedData // prints ImmutableMultiDict([('ErrorMessage', u'Not able to connect'), ('SiteId', u'12345'), ('CommandResult', u'201'), ('IsSuccessfull', u'true')])//
```

I want to get dictionary data. What is the request method I have to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call `to_dict` on the `ImmutableMultiDict`:

```
>>> imd = ImmutableMultiDict([('ErrorMessage', u'Not able to connect'),
('SiteId', u'12345'), ('CommandResult', u'201'), ('IsSuccessfull', u'true')])
>>> imd.to_dict()
{'ErrorMessage': 'Not able to connect', 'SiteId': '12345', 'CommandResult': '201',
 'IsSuccessfull': 'true'}
```

Comment: Why isn't the 'true' converted to Python boolean 'True' while doing `imd.to_dict()`? I have gone through all of stackoverflow answers but haven't found an answer.

Comment: @RomitThat sounds like a great question. Why don't you [ask it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)? Feel free to [drop me the URL](https://phihag.de/)

Comment: I am quite new to SO any help would be much appreciated. :)
Link to question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63214893/how-to-convert-form-response-data-to-python-dictionary-in-flask