# How to convert FORM response data to Python dictionary in Flask?

Tags: python, flask

I have the following data in POST format

Header: `Content-Type: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'`:

Data: `'field1=true&field2=false&field3=123'`

In the flask server, using the `response.form`, yields the following result:

`ImmutableMultiDict([('field1', 'true'), ('field2', 'false'), ('field3', '123')])`

After doing:
`request.form.to_dict()`

Result is:
`{'field1': 'true', 'field2': 'false', 'field3': '123'}`

Is there a way to convert the JSON boolean **true/false** to Python Boolean **True/False**?
Shouldn't the to_dict function convert these to python boolean types?

The dictionary is converted, but the true/false remains a string.

What is the optimal way to achieve this, besides using string comparison?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to `marshal` the data i.e refer - https://flask-restful.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html.

```
In [11]: from flask_restful import fields, marshal

In [12]: data = {'field1': 'true', 'field2': 'false', 'field3': '123'}

In [13]: mfields = { 'field1':fields.Boolean, 'field2':fields.Boolean, 'field3':fields.Raw}

In [14]: marshal(data, mfields)
Out[14]: OrderedDict([('field1', True), ('field2', True), ('field3', '123')])

In [17]: dict(marshal(data, mfields))
Out[17]: {'field1': True, 'field2': True, 'field3': '123'}
```

Use a serialization library such as [Marshmallow](https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to handle form data.

Edit:
In case you don't know the form structure before hand, you will have to convert it manually because `true` is a string here. If it wasn't then `json.loads` could be used.

```
In [18]: data
Out[18]: {'field1': 'true', 'field2': 'false', 'field3': '123'}

In [19]: {k: True if v == "true" else False if v == "false" else v for k,v in data.items()}
Out[19]: {'field1': True, 'field2': False, 'field3': '123'}
```

Comment: marshal works fine so long as I know what fields to expect, but what can be done for the fields whose data type isn't known beforehand?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! As I have mentioned in the last sentence of my question, I would like to do it without string comparison.

Comment: @Romit I have provided why it can't be done without string comparison in my answer